# Stop gradle build when a unit test fails

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I have found many posts on how to continue a gradle build when a unit test fails, however I cannot find any posts for how to stop for fail a build if a test fails. Is it possible to stop a debug build when a unit test fails?

Comment: AFAIK, you can tell gradle to continue on test fails. So, I guess, when you don't tell gradle to continue on test fails, it will .. stop !?

Comment: The "continue" functionality relates to subsequent tasks running after the test task. I believe the question is asking to stop in the middle of the test task which is not the opposite of "continue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `build.gradle`

```
test.afterTest { TestDescriptor td, TestResult tr ->
    if (tr.resultType == ResultType.FAILURE) {
        throw new Exception("$td failed")
    } 
}
```

Comment: To get this working I needed to add the following import: "import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult.ResultType"

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately solution from accepted answer didn't solve this problem. I found out that starting from Gradle 4.6 there is a `failFast` setting for test setup.

Adding this to `build.gradle` will stop execution of test cases:

```
test {
    failFast = true
}
```

You can read more about it in [official release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#fail-fast-option-for-test-tasks) and [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_execution).

Comment: where can I can put this in Android's build.gradle files? I tried inside `android {}` block and outside, none compiled :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--fail-fast` command-line option to `test`.